# Firefox not recognizing new ssl cert on local site

Tags: ssl-certificate

I created a new Drupal 8 site (latest version) on my Mac, using MAMP to test locally. I'd been using a self-signed SSL certificate, and yesterday purchased a Comodo PositiveSSL Multi-Domain (DV) cert. The site comes up fine in Safari and Chrome with the new cert, but Firefox (78.0.2) is still looking at the cold cert. I've tried clearing all caches, clearing the history cache, even rebooting; nothing seems to help. Is the old one being cached somewhere? Comodo said it should work and to ask Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution when I asked Firefox support forum:

follow the step:

click the 3 horizontal line top right browser screen.
click Help and select restart with Add-ons Disable.
Goto Safe Mode

click the 3 horizontal line top right browser screen . click the new private window.

I did so and re-enabled extensions and restarted, perfect!